# Can we call a trigger function in a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

Can we call a trigger function in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is automatically executed.  So, dependant on what your Stored Procedure is doing, it will get called.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/triggers.html

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to explictly call a trigger function.

Comment: As far as i know there isn't. Triggers are only automattically executed.

Comment: Can we supress the action that caused the trigger to fire when we met some criteria in the trigger.

Comment: ex:
In my stored procedure i have and insert statement on table xxxxx.

I have trigger on xxxxxx table on before insert.

In the trigger im checking if there exists a record with same id on the table,if i found any record i will update the table and should not allow to the insert to be executed.

Comment: Just return NULL to suppress.